# What should I do in this case?

Tags: android, fragment

I have antwo fragments like this:
[image]

What I want is when I press the "MapView" button, the whole screen will be like this:
[image]

so what should I do in this case to have the best UX? should I turn two fragments off and add a new one? Pleases give me some ideas! Thank you!

Comment: well,this is a q/a site for coding troubles only,you can always goto http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It's better to convert the whole stuff into 4 fragments.

Fragment 1: Search Bar

Fragment 2: Two Buttons

Fragment 3: Bottom list

Fragment 4: The map

So in this case you can listen to click on each button and replace the corresponding container having fragment 3 with fragment 4. If your design requires to hide fragment 1, it could also be done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent layout which will have two buttons at top. MapView and List View. Then Display desired Fragment with click on button through java code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="MapView" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="ListView" />
 <fragment
 android:name="com.example.app.myFragment"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment" 
 />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't a FrameLayout replace that fragment block so the Fragment can be dynamically replaced? Also, this will  look nothing like the UI shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a `PagerTitleStrip` layout. Just replace the content below the title strip by a fragment transaction. Feel free to ask, if you need further information (how to set it up).
A good starting point are the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html), the [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#scrollable) and maybe this [tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-pagertabstrip-pagertitlestrip-viewpager/).

Btw: one of my apps does a similar job, have a look: [Libre Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pepperonas.libredrive)